# Mounting and AWS EFS volume to Minikube

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, minikube, amazon-efs, argo-workflows

I'm using Argo workflows, minikube, and Docker to develop a local test environment for a production application. I would like to mount an EFS volume to minikube and
I'm having trouble finding documentation for doing this as most documentation and write-ups focus on EFS mounts to Kubernetes hosted on something like AWS EC2.

Essentially, I would like my container running on minikube to pull files from a mounted EFS, process that file, and save that file again to EFS.

I'm looking for information on how to configure and mount an EFS volume/pvc to my minikube cluster so that I can reference it in my Argo workflow template. Any help is greatly appreciated!